# ¿Es aconcejable guardar archivos en el local storage?

Tags: javascript, angular

en este momento tengo una duda respecto a guardar archivos en el local storage, resulta que estoy trabajando en un formulario que segun las opciones requiere ciertos archivos, antes de enviar esta informacion con dichos archivos paso a otro interfaz preliminar donde se muestran los datos anteriormente diligenciados. Estos archivos los guardo en el local storage en base 64, en caso de que el navegador se refresque y la informacion se borre entonces puedo recuperarla desde alli. Hay que tener en cuenta que una vez en la interfaz de preliminar el usuario podra editar esta informacion volviendo al formulario.

En terminos generales la duda es: **¿Es buena practica guardar archivos en el local storage?** he tenido problemas cuando son muchos archivos y chrome me arroja un error donde se indica que el local storage esta lleno.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Este es el error que se presenta cuando tengo muchos archivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso depende si es necesario pues si utiliza el local storafe pero también puedes usar la cache para guardar los datos y a lavez que la página sea más rápida y también puedes ver los archivos sin conexión

Comment: Parece buena opción, excepto si los archivos son muchos o muy grandes, _localStorage_, supongo que tiene límites y dependerá de sistema operativo y navegador la forma de manejarlos. Más información: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria#storage_limits

Comment: Si LocalStorage está excediendo la cuota los hechos hablan por sí solos: o debes optimizar los archivos reduciendo espacio (si esto es posible) o debes pensar en un almacenamiento más potente o distribuir responsabilidades entre las distintas posibilidades: por ejemplo, usar LocalStorage para cosas pequeñas e [IndexDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) para cosas más grandes... Todavía te queda la caché como medio de almacenamiento. Si aún así sigues teniendo problemas, definitivamente tendrás que pasar a una BD en el servidor o pensar en Firebase o algo así.

Comment: Entiendo muchas gracias por sus aportes, investigare sobre estas posibles soluciones